Change gpio state for Yocto based project
I am trying to do my first hardware "Hello, world" application, i. e. to blink some LED. Unfortunately, I do not have a success. Program and image are built sucessfully, program is executed successfully on the chip, but pin state is not changed.
Probably, I miss something in Yocto configuration? I am guessing that I missed some pins configuration. As far as I understand, there are 2 ways. It is possible to configure it at a receipt level that is preferable for me. Also it is possible to configure it at a software level.
I am using gpiod library. This is qsbase2 board, qs8m-mq00 mcu from Ka-Ro (NXP i.MX 8M), karo-image-minimal as a base.
I made gpioblinking layer with files as follows:
layer.conf:
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"
BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "gpioblinking"
BBFILE_PATTERN_gpioblinking = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_gpioblinking = "6"
LAYERDEPENDS_gpioblinking = "core"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_gpioblinking = "mickledore"

gpioblinking_1.0.bb:
SUMMARY = "bitbake-layers recipe"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
DESCRIPTION = "This is test image."
SRC_URI = "file://CMakeLists.txt file://main.cpp"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
DEPENDS = "libgpiod"
inherit pkgconfig cmake
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${B}/gpioblinking ${D}${bindir}/gpioblinking
}

main.cpp:

#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <gpiod.hpp>

using namespace std::string_literals;

static const std::string CONSUMER = "gpioblinking"s;
static const std::filesystem::path CHIP("/dev/gpiochip0");
static const ::gpiod::line::offset LINE_OFFSET = 3;
static const int ITERATIONS = 10;
static const std::chrono::milliseconds DELAY{ 500 };

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "- gpioblinking App"s << std::endl;

        ::gpiod::chip chip(CHIP);

        std::cout << "- Request "s << CHIP << ":"s << LINE_OFFSET << " for consumer "s << CONSUMER << " as output... "s;
        auto request =
            ::gpiod::chip(CHIP)
            .prepare_request()
            .set_consumer(CONSUMER)
            .add_line_settings
            (
                LINE_OFFSET,
                ::gpiod::line_settings().set_direction(::gpiod::line::direction::OUTPUT)
            )
            .do_request();
        std::cout << "OK"s << std::endl;

        if (!request)
            throw std::runtime_error("Request object is not valid"s);

        for (size_t cntr = 0; cntr < ITERATIONS; ++cntr)
        {
            if (request.get_value(LINE_OFFSET) == ::gpiod::line::value::ACTIVE)
                request.set_value(LINE_OFFSET, ::gpiod::line::value::INACTIVE);
            else
                request.set_value(LINE_OFFSET, ::gpiod::line::value::ACTIVE);

            std::cout << "- current value: "s << (request.get_value(LINE_OFFSET) == ::gpiod::line::value::ACTIVE ? "ACTIVE"s : "inactive"s) << std::endl;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(DELAY);
        }

        std::cout << "- Done"s << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
    catch (const std::exception err)
    {
        std::cerr << "* Exception: "s << err.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "* Unknown exception" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(gpioblinking VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(LIBGPIOD REQUIRED libgpiodcxx)

add_executable(gpioblinking)

target_compile_features(gpioblinking PRIVATE cxx_std_23)

target_link_libraries(gpioblinking PRIVATE ${LIBGPIOD_LIBRARIES})

target_include_directories(gpioblinking PRIVATE ${LIBGPIOD_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_sources(gpioblinking
    PRIVATE
        main.cpp
)

install(
    TARGETS gpioblinking
    DESTINATION bin
)

gpioblinking-image.bb:
SUMMARY = "gpioblinking image"

require ../../meta-karo-distro/recipes-core/images/karo-image-minimal.bb

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " gpioblinking"

The image is done as bitbake gpioblinking-image command.

Are you sure you have the right pin?  The mapping from GPIO number to external pin might not be what you expect. Why pin 3? Aside - using request.get_value() here is inefficient as it requires an ioctl call - just cache the last set value locally.

I tried different pins, in fact all chips and all pins. And I got the same result. So it looks that it is not pin number problem, but something more general.

So the program returns success?  Unfortunately I don't know much about setting up a platform with yocto.  I would build the gpiod tools and see what gpiodetect and gpioinfo tell you about the GPIO chip, to make sure the kernel and driver is setup correctly, and then try accessing the pins with gpioget and gpioset, which would take your code out of the equation and be easier for others to replicate.  Not that I see anything wrong obviously with your code.

"program is executed successfully on the chip, but pin state is not changed" - That's a bizarre definition of "success". The absence of reported errors is not necessarily "success"; errors can be silent or not obvious or ignored by your program. Your next step should be debugging the running Linux system (instead of reviewing the files in Yocto build system). Mount the debugfs, and examine the salient status files for the gpio and pinctrl subsystems. Run your program with strace to look for ignored errors..
